# iOS 6 Smart App Banner Cut Off

Tags: javascript, ios, banner

I am trying to add a smart app banner for users viewing through their mobile browser. I've been looking at some examples that use Javascript/CSS to work with other browsers besides Safari.

However, just dealing with Safari and iOS 6, when I add the meta tag for the smart app banner, it is displayed but cut half way off at the top of the page.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
http://i6.photobucket.com/albums/y201/WNxFiveStarKiller/ScreenShot2014-02-27at115725AM.png

I've tried adding Javascript which scrolls to the top of the page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
</script>
```

But that doesn't do the trick, seems like it thinks the top of the page is where it initially loads.

Any ideas how to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag placed in the head tag of you're HTML page should work:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

I would generally stay away from sliding the page up and down manually because the smart app banner usually slides down the whole page after the page has finished loading.

Comment: That is the meta tag that I am using and with no Javascript or CSS added it is still displaying cut off like in the screenshot I linked to.

Comment: Well I had a similar issue once were the app I was trying to display was only available on the US App Store, but I was loading the page from the UK and via a UK app store account. Is you're app available in the country you are developing the website from? If so, try using a VPN and/or try making the app available in more countries including you're own.